# "You've earned a bonus of 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network"

Tags: support, association-bonus

I've got this message for 5 SE sites, but my reputation level is only 316. I don't remember my reputation level exactly prior to this, but it was around 100 at the time, and I've lost almost none in the mean time. What happened?

I don't think this question is a duplicate, as  "...my reputation level is only 316...". I am not asking about why I got those bonuses. I asked why did I not get **all** of them.

Comment: explain what you mean by *"why did I not get all of them."* all of what? you have 5 accounts which all got 100 rep as explained in the answer at the end of the duplicate trail *"One of your linked accounts has reached 200 reputation points, and as a result, all associated accounts are given a 100 point bonus."*

Answer (score 22):

You earned over 200 rep on one site. This give you the bonus on all sites (including the one you got to 200 on, getting you to jump to > 300 there).

Comment: Read first, answer second.

Comment: **YOU DID GET ALL OF THEM**. Why do you think you did not? I can see you only have users on 5 sites, why do you expect to get reputation on the remaining 155 that you never registered on?

Comment: 5*100=500;500-316=184. So where did at least 184 points go?

Comment: They aren't additive, you don't get 500 points on one site, you get 100 points on each of the 5 sites you visit.

Comment: @ZzZombo - you don't get all of them **on one site**. You can +100 on each site. I see you have 101 on 4 sites (at this time), meaning - your 1 rep there + 100 association bonus. Why would you expect them all on one site??? We have 160 sites - you expect someone to register on one of them, and them suddenly get 16,000 reputation on one?

Comment: Because that's what the green number showed. I had no idea it somehow tracks changes across everything, and I see no mention of that anywhere either in the help. Question closed.

Comment: The green number aggregates reputation across all sites, yes. Seeing as you have only ever been active one one site, I can see how you wouldn't know that.